# How do I create a message box that fires a callback on button press?

Tags: gui, cocos2d-x, callbacks, cocos2d-x-js

I need to create a message box with an "OK"-button. When the user touches the button, it should execute a callback. I'm new to this and couldn't find any articles in the docs.

Comment: cocos2d-x v3.x ?

Answer (score 1):

I need too often to show popup message in my games. so I've created a base class and I derived new popup message class from it and override `SetupUI()` in derived class to show my desired message. in fact you need to put a `MenuItem` in `SetupUI()` of new class to implement "ok" button simply.

**Note:** `CreateInvisibleBackgroundButton()` works for cocos2dx v2.x and `BlockPassingTouch()` is its equivalent for cocos2dx v3.x .

**Note2:** If you want to call different callback for same popup message, you can pass a callback `std::function<void(void)> _callbackFunc` (cocos2dx v3) as parameter to your dialog and call that when "ok" pressed.

If you need more description just tell me.

**PopupNode.h**

```
#ifndef __POPUP_NODE_H__
#define __POPUP_NODE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"

class PopupNode : public cocos2d::Node
{
public:
    CREATE_FUNC(PopupNode);
    virtual bool init();    // subclass should have access to call it
    void ClosePopup();
private:
    void BlockPassingTouch();
    void SetupUI();
    void CreateInvisibleBackgroundButton(); //THIS FUNCTION IS OUTDATED. KEEP FOR COMPARING COCOS2D 2.X AND 3.X
};

#endif // __POPUP_NODE_H__
```

**PopupNode.cpp**

```
#include "PopupNode.h"
#include "Const/constants_z_order.h"

USING_NS_CC;


bool PopupNode::init()
{
    if ( !Node::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    BlockPassingTouch(); //CreateInvisibleBackgroundButton();
    SetupUI();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return true;
}

void PopupNode::CreateInvisibleBackgroundButton()
{
    // Code below works with cocos2dx 2.x
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////// THIS FUNCTION IS OUTDATED. KEEP FOR COMPARING COCOS2D 2.X AND 3.X
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
//  Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
//  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  auto lock_menu = Menu::create();
//  //lock_menu->setTouchPriority(-1000); // get touch first
//  lock_menu->setPosition(origin);
//  this->addChild(lock_menu);
//  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  auto invisibleClose = MenuItemSprite::create(NULL, NULL, nullptr);
//  invisibleClose->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT);
//  invisibleClose->setContentSize( visibleSize );
//  invisibleClose->setPosition(origin);
//  lock_menu->addChild(invisibleClose ); 
}

void PopupNode::SetupUI()
{
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    auto cover = Sprite::create("Scene/PopUp/LoadingBackground.png");
    cover->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
    this->addChild(cover, Z_BACKGROUND);
}

void PopupNode::BlockPassingTouch()
{
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    listener->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){
        if(event->getCurrentTarget()->isVisible() == false )
            return false;
        return true;
    };
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
}

void PopupNode::ClosePopup()
{
    this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Layer with an box and an CCMenu with one CCMenuItem.
The CCMenuItem will be your OK Button where you will set your callback method.

Something like...

> CCSprite *box = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"box.png"];
>
> box.position = ccp(screen.width/2,screen.height/2);
>
> [self addChild:box];
>
> CCMenuItemImage *okButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"yes.png" selectedImage:@"ok_button.png" target:self selector:@selector(okMethod)];
>
> CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:okButton,nil];
>
> menu.position = ccp(box.boundingBox.size.width/2,box.boundingBox.size.height/2);
>
> [box addChild:menu];

Hope it helps, :)

Comment: Notice that if there be a `MenuItem`(Button) back of your "box.png", touches will pass over this box ! you can handle this by putting a huge button which do nothing behind of your box.